# В EditText при вводе букв отрисовываются цифры

Tags: java, android

Создал простенькое приложение, состоящее из 2 активностей и 1 интента.

MainActivity:

```
public class CreateMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
    }

    public void onSendMessage(View view){
        EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        String messageTxt = message.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,RecieveMessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(RecieveMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,messageTxt);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Разметка для EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/send"
        android:layout_below="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10" />
```

Принимающая активность:

```
public class RecieveMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieve_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView recievedMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        recievedMessage.setText(text);
    }
}
```

В результате сообщения передаются и выводятся во второй активности,но вместо букв вводятся цифры. На приведенном скриншоте были введены кнопки q и w, что вылилось в 8 цифр.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Предлагаю сразу разделить задачу на три части и определить, где проблема. Выведите в лог `messageTxt` в первой активити и `text` во второй.

Comment: идея хорошая,но есть маленькое НО. в простой джаве я пользовался классами Syste.out.println(); как вывести в лог в андроид студии?в гуггле пишут,что есть LogCat,но он показывает общие  сведения и как его натравить на вывод нужных нам данных я не совсем понимаю..

Comment: @Iga тут также можно, sout тоже работает.

Comment: @Iga, [Как работать с LogCat](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/logcat.php).

Comment: `Log.d("happy", "твое сообщение '" + messageTxt + "'");`   Поскольку слов `happy` в логе исчезающе мало, по нему удобно фильтровать.

Comment: У вас при вводе получаются цифры  (нажимая на клавиатуре буквы вы получаете в поле ввода цифры) или при передаче в другое активити буквы превращаются в цифры

Comment: @tse добавил эту строку в активити. чтобы увидеть логи,нужно зайти в Android Monitor, вкладка LogCat?В статье,которую привели выше пишут про какой-то журнал..

Comment: @pavlofff да, цифры получаются при вводе букв с клавиатуры.

Comment: @lga https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Answer (score 4):

Сложно не заметить что 0439 это q, а 0446 это w в кодировке Unicode. Если используете Windows то поменяйте кодировку Android Studio с UTF-8 на windows-1252.

Comment: А как кодировка на хосте может влиять на работу со строкой в приложении?? Она же на устройстве создается, и на устройстве же отображается, никакого захардкоженного текста, который мог бы оказаться не в той кодировке. Поясните.

Comment: кодировку MainActivity с utd-8  на указанную вами поменял(также для эксперимента попробовал 1251).результат тот же..

Comment: Это проблема в телефоне, я у себя сделал тоже самое и у меня все работает. Моежете сказать какой телефон используете, прошивку и клавиатуру?

Comment: я использую  Geany Motion(т.к процессор амд).в нем создал 2 телефона- motorolla moto x api-17 4.2.2 и custom phone 4.2.2. на обоих проблемы с вводом.

Comment: подозреваю что проблема в джени моушене. У меня точно такой код работает без ошибок. У вас есть физическое устройство чтобы протестировать?

Comment: @ArnisShaykh да,физичекое устройство есть.попробую проверить сегодня